# accept only letters in a prompt box

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate the name prompt box to only allow letters and to make sure there is something put in there. There has to be an if and an else statement in there. I'm not sure why it isn't working but it just runs through as if there isn't an if statement there.

```js
function validate() {
    var name = prompt("Please enter your name.");
    var enquiry = prompt("Please tell us your enquiry.") 

    if (name = null || name == "") {
        alert("You must enter your name into the prompt box!");
        validate()
    } else if (!/[a-zA-Z]/name.test(ch)) {
        alert("Please only enter letters");
        validate()
    } else {
        alert("Your enquiry has gone through");
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: What a mess, please indent your code properly when you ask some help :/

Comment: Also consider that some names contain é Ä ö, ... these charcters, they would fail with your check.

Comment: `!/[a-zA-Z]/name.test(ch)` is not valid, you should use `!/[a-zA-Z]/.test(name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues with your code.

First, your if statement contains an assignment instead of comparison. You should change it to `==` or `===`:

```
if (name === null || name === "") {
```

Note: You should research the difference between `==` and `===` because you will get unexpected results as it stands. I would suggest you use `===` in this case.

Second, your regex syntax is wrong. It is just invalid as it stands.

Third, your actual regex won't do what you need as currently it will match is *any* character is a letter, rather than all of them. You should change it.

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name))
```

Full working code:

```
function validate() {
  var name = prompt("Please enter your name.");
  var enquiry = prompt("Please tell us your enquiry.")

  if (name == null || name == "") {
    alert("You must enter your name into the prompt box!");
    validate()
  } else if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name)) {
    alert("Please only enter letters");
    validate()
  } else {
    alert("Your enquiry has gone through");
  }
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj4w0qok/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name = 0.

Should be name == 0

```
if (name == null || name ==""){
    alert("You must enter your name into the prompt box!");
        validate()
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like a typo

```
if (name = null || name == "")
```

should be

```
if (name == null || name == "")
```

Your version (interestingly) will set name to `"true"` or `"false"` because it gets parsed as `name = (null || name == "")`